# Replace all non digits with an empty character in a string

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
public static String removeNonDigits(final String str) {
   if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
       return "";
   }
   return str.replaceAll("/[^0-9]/g", "");
}
```

This should only get the Digits and return but not doing it as expected! Any suggestions?

Comment: If you look at String.replaceAll method, you will see that it's doing Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement) which is inefficient if you are doing this a lot.  A better way would be to extract the compiled pattern into a constant.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Java is not Perl :) Try `"[^0-9]+"`

Comment: @whyoz: Please ask a new question

Comment: @whyoz: No one is ever going to find the answer in a comment.

Comment: "[^0-9.]+" will keep the decimal, if you happened upon this post needing to do so

Comment: I wish a Perl regular expressions in Java

Comment: @AaronDigulla: how to include negative numbers also? I mean, I have to replace everything that is not a positive/negative number with an empty space. How to do that?

Comment: @PankajSinghal: I'm almost sure this isn't possible with regexp. I suggest to ask a new question, maybe someone knows a trick.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421885/replace-everything-except-positive-negative-numbers) on this. Seems it's possible. :)

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
public static String removeNonDigits(final String str) {
   if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
       return "";
   }
   return str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the slash (for Java's sake, not the regex): "\\D+"

Answer (score 7):

Use following where `enumValue` is the input string.

```
enumValue.replaceAll("[^0-9]","")
```

This will take the string and replace all non-number digits with a "".

eg: input is _126576, the output will be 126576.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String replaceNonDigits(final String string) {
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return string.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
}
```

This does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend for this particular case just having a small loop over the string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (ch =='0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' ...) {
        sb.add(ch);
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Character.isDigit(...) is a better option than '(ch =='0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2'....)' IMO.