# Replace everything except positive/negative numbers

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

There are many questions already answered for replacing everything positive numbers. But, I couldn't find any answer which preserves both positive and negative numbers. I want to replace everything that isn't number(positive or negative). The output should be the following eg.

`0 | success. id - 1234|` -> `0 1234`

and

`-10 | failure. id - 2345|` -> `-10 2345`

Apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486309/820410) answers for the positive part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match positive/negative integers:

```
[+-]?\b\d+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG1eZ1/2)

to match positive/negative numbers including decimals:

```
[+-]?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

Please note that rather than using replace you would be better off using above regex in `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs and just get your matched data.

---

In case you can only use replace then use:

```
str = str.replaceAll( "([+-]?\\b\\d+\\b)|\\S+[ \\t]*", "$1" );
```

[Replace Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG1eZ1/3)

Comment: what is the use of equals sign?

Comment: 0 | success. id - 1234| is returning 01234 and not 0 1234 in your replaceall regex

Comment: Hmm [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG1eZ1/3) shows a space between `0` and `1234` but replace is not recommended, better to use matching.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in Kotlin to replace all non-Double characters before parsing to a Double:

```
val double = str.replace("[^0-9.-]".toRegex(), "").toDoubleOrNull()
```